# Search for numeric values within cells containing both alpha and numeric values-VBA Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have a spreadsheet with one column, Column "M," that has rows containing alpha numeric values like the following: 103.14   Jose Dolorez Chavez. I am not sure if there is code out there that can loop through each row of cells, cut the numerical values and paste them into an adjacent column. So At the end, I would have:
one column: 103.14      another column: Jose Dolores Chavez

Could someone help me. I'm not sure where to start. The code would need to loop through all 500 rows in column "M," find/cut the values, and paste them into column "N."

Any advice would be greatly appreciated and thank you in advance.

Comment: Is the pattern always like your example, i.e., a number followed by the rest?  Could the number be after the name or in the middle?

Comment: No, the pattern remains the same throughout: Number, followed by Employee name.

Comment: I'm not sure i understand Siddharth. What do you mean?

Comment: @Dora: Oops I deleted the comment at I was posting an answer. See the answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a VBA function you can use.  It uses the Val function, which returns the numeric part at the beginning of a string.  Just put it in a regular code module in your workbook:

```
Function GetNumAtBeginOfString(StringWithNum)
GetNumAtBeginOfString = Val(StringWithNum)
End Function
```

Then in column O put this formula (assumning your data starts in row 2):

```
=GetNumAtBeginOfString(M2)
```

And if column N put this formula:

```
=TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(M2,O2,""))
```

... and copy down.

This leaves you with the original string and two new columns.  If you want you can copy and paste over the original.

EDIT: you can use this Excel formula in column O instead of the VBA function:

```
=MAX(IF(ISNUMBER(LEFT(M2,ROW($A$1:$A$100))*1),(LEFT(M2,ROW($A$1:$A$100))*1),0))
```

It's an array formula and must be entered with `Ctrl-Shft-Enter`

Comment: I tried it , i still have the one column with the number and the name. there are not separated.

Comment: You put the formulas in the other two columns, N and O, as it says above?  What results to those formulas show?

Comment: You need to have macros enabled and the VBA function in a regular module in your workbook.  See my edit for a non-VBA approach.  Or just follow Siddharth's advice, which is the best way to go!

Comment: + 1 I owe my answer to your first comment in question. That set me to thinking and was finally confirmed with Dora's reply. I am sure that had you known that fact earlier, even you would have suggested what I suggested. :)

Answer (score 4):

> No, the pattern remains the same throughout: Number, followed by Employee name. – Dora 13 mins ago

You do not need VBA for this. You can easily achieve this via Text To Columns.

Highlight Column M and click on Data | Text To Columns | Delimited

Select space as delimiter and click on finish and you are done. See snapshot [here](http://wikisend.com/download/154882/untitled.png)

Uploading the screenshot in `wikisend.com` as it seems like imgur is down today.

Comment: This is certainly the way to go.  But no fun :). +1 as always.

Comment: Thank you so much Sid!!!!!!! (hope it's ok i shortened your name) You Rock! I got the downloaded image, tried it and it worked!

Comment: @Dora: Yup Sid is just fine. Almost every one here refers to me as Sid :)

Comment: @SiddharthRout Why dind't you stick to `Sid Rout` for the user name? +1